# Python comprehension vs normal indexing

Tags: python, indexing, list-comprehension

Can someone explain me the behaviour of the python comprehension vs normal indexing in the following example.

```
ser1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

ser2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

[x for x in ser1 if x not in ser2]    gives 5

ser1[~ser1.isin(ser2)]
```

gives 1 , 2, 3 which is correct

how should I write my python comprehension in order to get the correct result?

Comment: if you use simple python lists instead of pandas classes, it works well

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
ser1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
ser2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
print([x for x in ser1 if x not in ser2]) # 5
```

What happend `not in` (and `in`) against `pd.Series` do regard indices not values, both `ser1` and `ser2` have their values numbered `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`, so `not in` holds only for `5`.
You should do membership test against values i.e.:

```
print([x for x in ser1 if x not in ser2.values]) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much; it's clear

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the values of the series solves the issue.

```
[x for x in ser1.values if x not in ser2.values]
```